# Metric Spaces: Question regarding the closure of a set E

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

just a quick question as i'm having difficulty visualising the reason why.

for $X$ non empty and $E \subset X$ and $\epsilon > 0$ we define

$$Int(E) = \{x \in X: \exists \epsilon > 0,~ B(x;\epsilon) \subset E\} $$

ie its the set of points in x which are interior points of E

and we define 
$$E' = \{x \in X:\forall \epsilon > 0,~ \left(B(x;\epsilon)\backslash\{x\}\right) \cap E \neq \emptyset)\}$$

but we define the closure of E to be denoted as

$$\bar{E} = E \cup E'$$

and this doesnt quite make sense to me. infact whilst writing this i may have figured out why someone let me know if im right?

i'm guessing it can be shown that $$Int(E) \subset E$$ but $$E' \not\subset E$$ or at least isnt necessarily a subset of E. my issue stems from the fact that surely E would contain the interior points and the limit points making the union redundent?

im guessing an example would be a value $x \in X$ which is outside the subset $E$ but the ball with radius $\epsilon$ overlaps E with an infinite number of $x \in \left(B(x;\epsilon)\backslash\{x\}\right) \cap E)$ which kind of makes that definition make more sense now.

is the above thinking correct? i appreciate any time you can spare.

**editted: added epsilon quantifiers to the definition of int(E) and E'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, but your definitions of interior and closure are missing some quantifiers over $\epsilon$. The inclusions $\text{int}E ⊆ E ⊆ \overline{E}$ always hold, and a basic example to keep in mind is $E=[0,1)$ on $X=\mathbb R$, giving
$$(0,1) ⊆ [0,1) ⊆ [0,1] $$
The point $1\in ℝ \setminus [0,1) = X\setminus E$ is a limit point and belongs to $E'$.

Comment: brilliant. thanks for the quick answer. i appreciate it and it's given me a good example.
just on another quick note. is it not sufficient to state $\epsilon > 0$ above before defining or should it really always be in the definitions themselves?